# what wrong with my code always print answer : null+word,what is null?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, file

We have file with a few words, try safe word with word have 2,4,6 or 8 letters in array but then save in screen write null and null+good word.

What did I write wrong, and why does it show null?

```
public static void lyginis () throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("words.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);
    int kiek = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        scanner.next();
        kiek++;
    }
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(path);
    String[] atrinkti = new String[kiek];
    String scan = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < kiek; i++) {
        scan = scanner1.next();
        if (scan.length() % 2 == 0) {
            atrinkti[i] += scan ;
        }
        System.out.println(atrinkti[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("words.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int kiek = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            scanner.next();
            kiek++;
        }
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(file);
        String[] atrinkti = new String[kiek];
        String word = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < kiek; i++) {
            word = scanner2.next();
            if (word.length() % 2 == 0) {
                atrinkti[i] = word;
                System.out.println(atrinkti[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
$ cat words.txt
hi
hello
whats up
chicken
duck
goose

$ javac Hello.java; java Hello
hi
up
duck
```

The issues were:

1. `Path` was used instead of `File`
2. The `+=` was used within the `if` statement instead of just `=`
3. The `System.out.println()` function was called outside of the `if` statement so when the word's length was not divisible by 2, the current array element would print the default initialized value of the array of `null`

Comment: @aurimas-butkevicius try using intellij in the future for debugging. It works really well for Java.